# Ubuntu Budgie: Is there a way to show a window in all workspaces?

Tags: workspaces, window-manager, virtualdesktop, ubuntu-budgie

In most desktop environments, you can set a window to be visible in all workspaces or virtual desktops.

I can not find this option in Ubuntu Budgie:

> [image]

Is it possible?

If not officially supported, are there workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that is what are you looking for, but you can set up shortcut for this function.
Open Dconf, move to /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-on-all-workspaces
and put your keys code to 'Custom value' field (for example `['<Alt>F8']`).
Press `<Alt>F8` on active window, and this window will be visible in all workspaces.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it sounds good. I have since migrated to a new PC, and switched to Linux Mint Mate, so I can't test it, and I don't want to approve the answer without having tested it. But I'll upvote it.